# Failure when registering EventProcessorHost

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-eventhub, event-processor-host

I am trying to use EventProcessorHost to consume messages from eventhub in JAVA. Followed steps which are given [here1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-receive-eph) and [here2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/blob/master/samples/Java/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/eventhubs/samples/Basic/EventProcessorSample.java) but when I run code I am getting below error..

```html
Registering host named <name>

Failure while registering: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The client could not finish the operation within specified maximum execution timeout.
    Press enter to stop
```

More details:

1. Created new storage account as mentioned in blog and also created blob.
2. EventProcessor class and ErrorNotificationHandler class are exactly as mentioned on Microsoft docs.
3. Code which calls register is as below...

   ```js
   final String consumerGroupName = "test";
   final String namespaceName = "--namespace--";
   final String eventHubName = "--eventhub name --";
   final String sasKeyName = "--saskey name--";
   final String sasKey = "--sas-key";
   final String containerName = "--container name --";
   final String storageAccountName = "--storage account name --";
   final String storageAccountKey = "--storage -- account key--";
   final String connectionString = "--eventhub connection string copied from azure portal --";
   final String storageConString = "--storage connection string copied from azure portal --";

       EventProcessorHost host = new EventProcessorHost(
       namespaceName, // Also tried with full name <namespace name>.servicebus.windows.net
       eventHubName,
       consumerGroupName,
       connectionString,
       storageConString,
       containerName
       //        "<blobprefix>" Also tried with blob prefix
       );

       System.out.println("Registering host named " + host.getHostName());
       EventProcessorOptions options = new EventProcessorOptions();
       options.setReceiveTimeOut(Duration.ofMinutes(12 L));
       options.setExceptionNotification(new ErrorNotificationHandler());

       try {

       host.registerEventProcessor(EventProcessor.class, options).get(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

       } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.print("Failure while registering: ");
       if (e instanceof ExecutionException) {
       Throwable inner = e.getCause();
       System.out.println(inner.toString());
       } else {
       System.out.println(e.toString());
       }
       }
   ```

Note: Blog has deprecated constructor for EventProcessorHost.

Searched for error online and what I could find is to increase the timeout for storage but not sure how can I prove specific timeout for storage in EventProcessorHost. Any help appreciated.

Comment: According to your error log , your process has not yet arrived at theIEventProcessor.onEvents method when the error occurred. setReceiveTimeOut did not solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you Jay for looking at this. No setReceiveTimeOut didn't solve the problem even though I have put 12 mins. I am not sure if there is another timeout I need to set.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce your issue and figure out how to solve this.(I notice that you posted a similar question before)

Comment: Yes, that was with different error, no replies to that. Just deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-receive-eph) to receive messages from event hub and it works well for me.

[image]

Messages were stored into Azure Blob Storage which I configured.

[image]

According to your description , the timeout Exception still occurred even though you set the ReceiveTimeOut to 12 mins in EventProcessorOptions. Per my experience , even if messages are received one by one, it can't take 12 minutes to do so long. And it's usually impossible for us to set the timeout so long in our application. So I think error is no longer from SDK level. It may be the network environment issue.

As I know , the Event Hub message send client uses the `HTTP protocol` and is won't be blocked by the firewall. The EPH message receive client uses the AMQP protocol which is essentially `TCP protocol` and is will restricted by proxy server settings or firewall. I assume your Eph client has no connection to Event hub.

I do not know your actual network environment,so I suggest you check your proxy settings or firewall white list to troubleshoot issues with the network environment.

Any concern , please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for doing this. I set ReceiveTimeOut that hight just to test it out, in case that works. I will check proxy settings, is there any specific proxy settings you know I should be looking for?

Comment: @user8828251 You could check the proxy settings in the code or in the system, whether it is SOCK4/5 proxy (support tcp protocol ).

Comment: Tried looking at proxy settings in my machine and I do not have any specific settings selected. Still not working, should I be selecting any specific proxy settings?